# Multi-device design speed concern

Tags: html, css, performance, responsive-design, mean-stack

My workplace is currently using a MEAN (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node.js) Stack with a multi-device design. They decided to not use responsive design, and I think it's too much effort to convert to responsive design after all the work. Here's the example of my page structure:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div class="desktop">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="tablet">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="mobile">
            ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The desktop, tablet, and mobile classes are being configured through CSS using Media Queries. Here's some example to determine which div should be displayed (In this case, the example is to show mobile class divs):

```
@media (max-width: 760px) {
    .desktop {
        display: none;
    }


    .tablet {
        display: none;
    }

    .mobile {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

Now at first it's easier to develop different layout for different devices, but it comes to this: load time becomes slower. I experimented with a one device design, which only have a desktop class div in a  tag. Here's the speed comparison of two pages, with different structure:

Page with 3 device design (desktop, tablet, and mobile)
[image: Page with 3 device design]

Page with one device design (only desktop)
[image]

Now comes the question, is there any solution to make page loads faster, besides moving to responsive design? I already reduced large resources such as pictures and external files imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responsive or not-responsive will not make any difference in download speeds/sizes. The largest bottleneck is usually is a large number of assets that are loaded sequentially.

Your figures show that as well. Download size is ~45kb in both, however something is loaded sequentially in the first. Check what it is, bundle together css/js, make use of sprites/icon fonts.

Remember that images are loaded regardless of the {display: none; } so be careful and maybe use js to set only images you need.

Comment: What if in the desktop, tablet, and mobile loads the same images? Like literally same src attribute value? Will it loads the images 3 times? Or just once?

Comment: Repeated images are taken from a browser cache. Can you show what requests are processed in the first fig?

Comment: It's kind of difficult to show it, but mostly stylesheets, scripts, and images.

Comment: Optimally, there should be one html, one css, one js file and optimized images. [link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization)